# How to pass the src attribute of the img tag to the child component through the parent component in vue

Tags: vue.js

I have a parent component and a child component, and I want to pass a src attribute to the child component via defineProps to make it display the image.

Below is my parent component code：

```
<script setup>
import item from "./item.vue";
const items=[
  {
    id:0,
    img:'../assets/2.png',
    name:'秘塔写作猫',
    des:'码文章必备工具'
  },
  {
    id:1,
    img:'../assets/2.png',
    name:'AdblockPlus广告拦截',
    des:'最流行的广告拦截拓展程序'
  },
  {
    id:2,
    img:'../assets/3.png',
    name:'Tampermonkey油猴脚本',
    des:'码文章必备工具'
  },
  {
    id:3,
    img:'../assets/4.png',
    name:'蔚蓝主页',
    des:'个性化简洁风格浏览器主页'
  },
  {
    id:4,
    img:'../assets/5.png',
    name:'ABCD PDF',
    des:'完全免费在线PDF压缩转换工具'
  },
  {
    id:5,
    img:'../assets/6.png',
    name:'ASO谷歌商店工具',
    des:'洞悉竞品下载、评论等核心数据'
  },
]
</script>

<template>
  <div id="ain">
    <div id="head">
      <h4>站长推荐</h4>
      <a>查看全部</a>
    </div>
    <div id="body">
      <item v-for="item in items" :key="item.id"  :img="item.img" :name="item.name" :des="item.des">
      </item>  
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Below is my subcomponent code：

```
<script setup>
  defineProps(['img','name','des'])
</script>

<template>
  <div id="item">
    <div>
        <img src="img">
        <p>{{name}}</p> 
        <p id="detail">{{des}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

This error is displayed in the console:GET http://127.0.0.1:5173/assets/2.png 404 (Not Found)

I think it's a problem with passing parameters, but I don't know how to modify it, thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions
1.You can use an absolute path
2.Put your image in the public path under the root directory

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using `Vite` and there are a few options to reference images:

1. Use import statements for images to obtain the image URL

```
import imgUrl from './assets/img.png'
document.getElementById('hero-img').src = imgUrl
```

2. Place images inside `public` folder and reference using `/`. For example if all images are contained inside `public/img` then the URL would be `/img`.
3. Try `new URL(url, import.meta.url)` although this does not work with SSR

Number **2)** is probably the easiest if these images won't be updated.

Reference:
https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html